# Upload Xslx File to SQL Server using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to upload some files(xlsx) from a folder using python but I'm stuck in a error with the for.

```
folder = os.chdir(r"C:\Users\800061199\Desktop\Teste_Base")
farqs = [arq for arq in os.listdir(folder) if arq.endswith('.xlsx')]

for arq in farqs:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, arq)
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    
    table = os.path.splitext(arq)[0]
    df.to_sql(table, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Comment: Looks like arq is an INT or something, need to convert to string first to combine.

Comment: os.chdir doesn't do what you think it does. it changes dir and probably returns None

Comment: you probably just wants listdir(r"c:\users...")

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder = r"C:\Users\800061199\Desktop\Teste_Base"
farqs = [arq for arq in os.listdir(folder) if arq.endswith('.xlsx')]

for arq in farqs:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder, arq)
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    
    table = os.path.splitext(arq)[0]
    df.to_sql(table, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

The folder variable is None when you're trying to join it with `arq` to create the `file_path`. This can happen if the `chdir()` function fails to change the current directory.

You need to provide the full path to the folder directly in `os.listdir()` instead of using `os.chdir()` to ensure that `os.listdir()` receives the correct path.